# Программа не видит файл "client_secrets.json" - PyDrive

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я скачал json файл и поместил его в одной директории с моей программой, как и указано в документации PyDrive, но при запуске программы выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 121, in _loadfile
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 386, in LoadClientConfigFile
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 124, in _loadfile
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError('Error opening file', exc.filename,
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mapk0/Desktop/Login Data Decrytor/Login_Data_Decrytor.py", line 6, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 113, in _decorated
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 443, in GetFlow
    self.LoadClientConfig()
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 366, in LoadClientConfig
    self.LoadClientConfigFile()
  File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 388, in LoadClientConfigFile
    raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

Как я понял, ошибка заключается в том, что модуль не смог обнаружить файл "client_secrets.json"

Comment: Не уверен, но, возможно, не видит файл из-за имени `PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0` в пути. Проверьте, или имя файла, который требуется открыть - правильно указан у вас в коде. Также попробуйте запустить свой код в виртуальном окружении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было запускать программу из командной строки.